# Can "should" be used in program test plan

Tags: grammar

For example

Steps:
 1. Enter "1+1"
 2. Press "Enter"

Expected result:
Program should output 2

My reasoning is that it is short form of 
"In order to pass this test program should output 2"

But argument can be made that as it is necessary to output to be 2, one should use "must" instead of "should".

So what is correct way to say it?

Comment: What's wrong with "will"? `The program will output 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is valid, and correct, but there is ambiguity.  The ambiguity with modals in English is often leveraged in order to appear polite, gentle, or deferential to someone of higher social status.

As the context is technical, precision is preferred, and you should be direct and prefer *must* to clearly communicate the requirement, unless there is an external need to be friendly.